# I want to change the "orderID" of an "array1" whose "productID"=1 according to "array2" (array of "id")

Tags: javascript

```
let array1 = [
    { id:1, name:'name1', orderId:3, productID:1},
    { id:2, name:'name2', orderId:2, productID:1},
    { id:3, name:'name3', orderId:1, productID:2},
    { id:4, name:'name4', orderId:4, productID:1},
    { id:5, name:'name5', orderId:2, productID:2},
    { id:6, name:'name6', orderId:4, productID:2},
    { id:7, name:'name7', orderId:3, productID:1}
]
```

I want to change the "orderID" of an  "array1" whose "productID"=1

```
let array2 = [4,2,7,1];   // this is an array of "id"
```

I want to change the "orderID" of an "array1" whose "productID"=1
In "array2" if "id" is "4" than object will
{ id:4, name:'name4', orderId:1, productID:1}

In "array2" if "id" is "2" than object will
{ id:2, name:'name2', orderId:2, productID:1}

In "array2" if "id" is "7" than object will
{ id:7, name:'name7', orderId:3, productID:1}

In "array2" if "id" is "1" than object will
{ id:1, name:'name1', orderId:4, productID:1}

```
for (let i of array1){
    // console.log(i)
    for (let j in i){
        // console.log(j)
        // console.log(i[j])
        for (let k of array2)
        {
            if ((j==='id' && i[j]===k) && "orderID"){
             console.log(i)
        }
    }
    }
}
```

```
// expected output = 
// [   { id:1, name:'name1', orderId:4, productID:1},
//     { id:2, name:'name2', orderId:2, productID:1},
//     { id:3, name:'name3', orderId:1, productID:2},
//     { id:4, name:'name4', orderId:1, productID:1},
//     { id:5, name:'name5', orderId:2, productID:2},
//     { id:6, name:'name6', orderId:4, productID:2},
//     { id:7, name:'name7', orderId:3, productID:1}   ]
```

Comment: `&& "orderID"` is completely redundant and can be removed. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with digital signature algorithm (DSA). Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could map objects with new `orderId` where `id` is given.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: 'name1', orderId: 3, productID: 1 }, { id: 2, name: 'name2', orderId: 2, productID: 1 }, { id: 3, name: 'name3', orderId: 1, productID: 2 }, { id: 4, name: 'name4', orderId: 4, productID: 1 }, { id: 5, name: 'name5', orderId: 2, productID: 2 }, { id: 6, name: 'name6', orderId: 4, productID: 2 }, { id: 7, name: 'name7', orderId: 3, productID: 1 }],
    ids = [4, 2, 7, 1],
    result = data.map(o => {
        const orderId = ids.indexOf(o.id) + 1;
        return orderId
            ? { ...o, orderId }
            : o
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```